# How can I find the location of a file in the system path, like get-command or where?

Tags: c#, windows, filepath

I want to find whether a certain DLL is available on the system path. in Powershell, I can use `get-command myfile.dll`, and in cmd I can use `where myfile.dll`.

How can I do that in C#? Do I have to manually parse `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path")`, or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know what *"better"* means to you, but [AssocQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw) can do that for you.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks, but that brings in a bunch of shell-specific behaviors I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about `where`, but `Get-Command` internally resolves the file location using the following algorithm (overly simplified):

1. Parse `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")`
2. Enumerate all files in each individual `PATH` entry with `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`
3. Perform a case-insensitive string comparison with the input file name against each file name in the directory

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm left with re-implementing this logic by myself. I was looking for a ready-made solution, I guess there isn't one.

Comment: No, problem is it's baked into library load functions in Windows and not directly exposed. I should add that `Get-Command` also resolves the system and windows directories before searching path, more or less like safe [library loads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)